# Polyglot installation in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install the tool Polyglot. When setup file run an error occur. I installed all the required packages . The error is :

```
Running pycld2-0.31/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-mZGHbc/pycld2-0.31/egg-dist-tmp-TKDn8z
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
                 from cld2/internal/scoreonescriptspan.h:76,
                 from cld2/internal/cldutil.h:25,
                 from cld2/internal/cldutil.cc:20:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is;

> /usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such
>   file or directory

This mainly indicates you are building 32bit on a 64 bit machine so to solve that

try to install the package `gcc-multilib`

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

if you already have it or this doesn't work then try to install

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```